# Format phone number column to (555)555-5555

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

My data looks like this: 347 210-4961

I want to format it to this: (555)555-5555

I've tried the following

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(HOME_PHONE,'(',''),' ',''),'-',''),')','')
```

But its come out like this: 7184455900

My database comparability is at SQL Server 2005

Comment: Data formatting belongs in a presentation layer.

Comment: Yes, but in this case it should be normalized and cleansed in database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be overthinking it.

```
DECLARE @ VARCHAR(20) = '347 210-4961'

SELECT '(' + REPLACE(@, ' ', ')')
```